# Javascript convert data from one format so another so code can read it

Tags: javascript, arrays

If have some code which is reading some data which looks like this:

```
[[1423008000000,1],[1423094400000,1]]
```

I have now been give some other data in a different format which looks like this:

```
{"1300752000000":11,"1301356800000":4}
```

I've got the data in a variable called data.

My question is, how can I convert the bottom example to look like the example at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using `map` function like below,

```
var data = {"1300752000000":11,"1301356800000":4};
var res = Object.keys(data).map(itm => [itm, data[itm]]);

console.log(res); //[["1300752000000", 11],["1301356800000", 4]]
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return enumerable own properties from the supplied object. So from that key array, we can translate it to the array that we wanted by using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the result.

```js
var data = { "1300752000000": 11, "1301356800000": 4 },
    array = Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
        return [k, data[k]];
    });

console.log(array);
```